# execl in multiple forks in C runs synchronously / blocking

Tags: c, exec, fork

I have 2 simple programs that I use to modify text files.

The first one receives a commands file and a list of files to modify. The second program is made to be run by the first one, receives as a parameter a file to be read then reads commands from the stdin, execute them on the file and display to the stdout when it's done. Repeat.

My problem is that each fork seems to be waiting for the others to finish all it's commands rather than starting its own.

**Main program**

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    ...

    // Multiple forks
    for(i=2; i < argc; i++){

        ...

        pipe(pipes[forks]);
        forks++;

        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) break;

        ...
    }

    if(pid == 0){
        dup2(pipes[forks-1][0], STDIN_FILENO);

        // Execute the second program in the fork, 
        // pass a file to be read as a single argument
        execl("second_program", "second_program" , argv[i], NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "execl() failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    } else {

        ...

        // Reads a file containing commands, normalize it and output a string
        char *cmds = getcmds(argv[1]);
        int f;
        for(f=0; f < forks; f++){
            // Send the list of commands to the second program
            write(pipes[f][1], cmds, strlen(cmds));
        }

        wait(NULL);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

**Child program**

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    ...

    char buffer[READ_SIZE];
    do {

        scanf("%s",buffer);
        if(strcmp(buffer,"COMMAND_A") == 0){

            ...
            printf("`COMMAND_A on %s\n", filename);

        } if(strcmp(buffer,"COMMAND_b") == 0){

            ...
            printf("`COMMAND_b on %s\n", filename);

        } else {
            break;
        }

        ...                             

    } while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example output I'm getting**

```
COMMAND_A on file1
COMMAND_B on file1
...
COMMAND_Z on file1
COMMAND_A on file2
COMMAND_B on file2
...
COMMAND_Z on file2
COMMAND_A on file3
COMMAND_B on file3
...
COMMAND_Z on file3
```

The forks blocks and complete all theirs tasks rather than running in parallel. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forks start running concurrently, but they are all waiting for input through the pipe at the point of calling `scanf`. Try changing the order in which you `write`, and the order of the reads will change, too. Also, whenever `strlen(cmds)` exceeds `PIPE_BUF`, you may observe different results.

Writing something shorter than `PIPE_BUF` on a pipe is guaranteed to be delivered in one chunk at the other end. It's not that each command in your `cmds` wakes up the child processes.

Comment: I thought that by doing `write(pipes[f][1], cmds, strlen(cmds))` and write all the commands in a single time to their respective pipes, each fork would be free to read stdin when it's ready to do so.

Comment: Whenever the child processes call `scanf`, they are put in a wait-queue, waiting for input. When the parent writes to the pipe, the corresponding child is woken up almost synchronously. For finer granularity, you may consider splitting up the commands in `cmds` and sending each of them in a separate `write`.

Comment: I tried separating them but it didn't change anything. Still blocking. I get that `scanf` puts the process on wait but once they've received their first command, shouldn't they overlap? I should get something like this: `COMMAND_A on file2, COMMAND_A on file1, COMMAND_A on file3, COMMAND_B on file2 ...`